# Excel - VBA code to add a column ID and then combine all sheets into a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel file with multiple sheets. Every sheet has the same format, for example:

Sheet 1: name "01"

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ Name ║ Value ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ a    ║     1 ║
║ b    ║     2 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Sheet 2: name "02"

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ Name ║ Value ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ c    ║     3 ║
║ d    ║     4 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

I want to combine all of these sheet into a new sheet like:

Sheet combine: name "combine"

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════╗
║ Name ║ Value ║ ID ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════╣
║ a    ║     1 ║ 01 ║
║ b    ║     2 ║ 01 ║
║ c    ║     3 ║ 02 ║
║ d    ║     4 ║ 02 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════╝
```

I found a VBA code to combine all sheet but I don't know how to add a column ID to each sheet before combine. The VBA code is:

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you very much if some one can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only two columns as you illustrated in your question. This should work.

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Sheets(1).range(sheets(1).cells(Sheets(1).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row, 3), sheets(1).cells(Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, 3)) = Sheets(j).name
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much DiegoAndresJAY,

I use your code with a little tweak for my problem and it works perfectly.

My code is:
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A965536").End(xlUp)(2)
Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Range("O965536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 15), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Range("A965536").End(xlUp).Row, 15)) = Sheets(J).Name

Answer (score 0):

I am at beginner level in Excel VBA, hence interested in trying various code fragments suggested in the forum. I wanted to comment only but do not have required points to comment.Hence putting my view as answer.

While trying the code @DiegoAndresJAY Column C values are not aligned with values in Column A and Column B. Minor tweaking the following line gives the correct alignment. Perhaps an oversight.

```
      Sheets(1).range(sheets(1).cells(Sheets(1).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row+1, 3), sheets(1).cells(Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row, 3)) = Sheets(j).name
```

Thank You